# My VAIO laptop isn't detecting my Bluetooth mouse

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I have a Microsoft mouse called Designer Bluetooth, anyways... when I click on add device, I click the button on my mouse, but my laptop doesn't detect it, I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a driver issue. Please make sure you have up-to-date drivers for your Bluetooth card. Try going on Device Manager and see whether your system at least detects the Bluetooth component. If yes then update its drivers.

Once the drivers are up to date, attempt to pair with the mouse as some mice only tend to work when they're paired with the system.

If this doesn't seem to work then visit Microsoft's brilliant [troubleshooting guide](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-gb/help/support/troubleshooting/mouse/wireless-bluetooth) written just for these sorts of issues.

Comment: There are "Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) and Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)" in the Network adapters, and "Generic Bluetooth Adapter and Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator" in the Bluetooth Radios section, which ones do I update?

Comment: I suggest you look up the exact name and model of your Bluetooth component and download the drivers from their website. These drivers should take care of this issue.

Comment: How do I get the model of my Bluetooth?

Comment: Try opening Device Manager and right-clicking the Bluetooth device and selecting properties. There's normally a plethora of information there.

Comment: Still, it detects my phone and my screen, but not the mouse.

Comment: Did you try updating the Bluetooth drivers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26616/discussion-between-pepsigam3r-and-kkmonlee).

Comment: Yes, I updated them from Atheros.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can use the designer Bluetooth mouse with your VAIO laptop until Sony releases up-to dated Bluetooth driver. I have 2 vaio laptops and tried to use the mouse several times. it failed.